# IBM Rational Software Architect 9 Install Error

Tags: rational-rsa

I want to install IBM Rational Software Architect 9 and i have this error message during the setup :

```
Locking is not possible in the directory D:\RSA9.0\RSA_SETUP\InstallerImage_win32_x86\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi. 
A common reason is that the file system or Runtime Environment does not support file locking for that location. 
Please choose a different location, or disable file locking passing "-Dosgi.locking=none" as a VM argument
```

Comment: I solved it. Uncheck "read only"

Comment: you can post you solution as a answer (provided you write something slighty longer than that )

Comment: This is not IBM Technical Support. If you're having installation issues, contact them directly.

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when you have incorrect permissions to edit the folder, or if it is set to read only. I would recommend looking into those first.

If that doesn't make any difference, try following the steps listed and passing the parameter to the install command. After that I would just recommend contacting IBM Directly for support.